# swiftUI, moving the view to where I tapped

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on moving the view to where I tapped. In my code below, my objective is moving is `redCircleView()` to the rectangle I tapped.

At first, I tried to get coordinate of where the user tapped, and pass that coordinate to offset of redCircleView(). The func I tried to use is this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: view)
     
    }
}
```

But I got some problem with calling with, and declaring class to embed this func in `ContentView.swift`

So instead I tried to get coordinate of each Rectangle when it got tapped.
Here is what my current code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentPos: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var newPos: CGSize = .zero
       
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { usa in
            ZStack{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).onTapGesture {
                                        let frame = usa.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.local)
                                       self.currentPos.width = frame.size.width
                                       self.currentPos.height = frame.size.height
                    }
                    Spacer()
                     Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).onTapGesture {
                                        let frame = usa.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.local)
                                        self.currentPos.width = frame.size.width
                                        self.currentPos.height = frame.size.height
                     }
                }
                
                HStack{
                     Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).onTapGesture {
                                        let frame = usa.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.local)
                                        self.currentPos.width = frame.size.width
                                        self.currentPos.height = frame.size.height
                     }
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).onTapGesture {
                                    let frame = usa.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.local)
                                       self.currentPos.width = frame.size.width
                                       self.currentPos.height = frame.size.height
                    }
                }
            }
                //end of VStack    
                redCircleView()
                     .offset(x: self.currentPos.width, y: self.currentPos.height)
                     .gesture(DragGesture()
                         .onChanged { value in
                             self.currentPos = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPos.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPos.height)
                            
                     }
                         .onEnded { value in
                             self.currentPos = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPos.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPos.height)
                           
                             self.newPos = self.currentPos
                         }
            )
            
            }
        }
        }
        
    }

struct redCircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
       .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

But the problem here is when I tap the rectangle, the redCircleView() got disappeared not moving to rectangle where I tapped. I guess the problem is at getting the coordinate of the rectangle where I taped but got no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. It needs to grab frame of each box in same coordinate space as circle moves, and then calculate needed translation. (Also extraction refactoring made, to helper function, to avoid code duplication).

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Re-tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentPos: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var newPos: CGSize = .zero

    private func generateBox(in usa: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).overlay(GeometryReader { gp in
            Color.black.onTapGesture {
                let area = usa.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.global)
                let frame = gp.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.global)
                let position = CGSize(width: frame.midX - area.midX, height: frame.midY - area.midY)

                self.newPos = position
                withAnimation {
                    self.currentPos = position
                }
            }
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { usa in
            ZStack{
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        self.generateBox(in: usa)
                        Spacer()
                        self.generateBox(in: usa)
                    }

                    HStack{
                        self.generateBox(in: usa)
                        Spacer()
                        self.generateBox(in: usa)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                //end of VStack
                redCircleView()
                    .offset(x: self.currentPos.width, y: self.currentPos.height)
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            self.currentPos = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPos.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPos.height)

                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        self.currentPos = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPos.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPos.height)

                        self.newPos = self.currentPos
                        }
                )

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Requires a Spacer() before and after the HStack instances to work as shown (Swift 5, Xcode 13.2)